# Restriction of the ample and the effective cones to a very ample smooth hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Y\subset X$ be a very ample smooth hypersurface in a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension at least $4$. By Lefschetz hyperplane theorem this embedding induces an isomorphism $\mathrm{NS}X\cong \mathrm{NS}Y$. Does this isomorphism induce an isomorphism on the cones of the pseudo-effective and nef divisors?

It is easy to see that the cone $\overline{\mathrm{NE^1}}(X)$ is a subcone of $\overline{\mathrm{NE^1}}(Y)$ and the same for $\overline{\mathrm{Eff^1}}(X)$. 
Are there additionals condition on $X$ and $Y$ to state an equality of the cones?

Comment: In general the answer to the question about the nef cone is no: there are counterexamples due to Hassett--Lin--Wang http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~dragon/Research%20papers/ample3.pdf

Comment: @Pop, Thank you.